# Add inputAccessoryToolbar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to add a minus operator to my NumberPad. How can I implement the inputAccessoryToolbar into my project and how do I add a minus operator to the NumberPad?

Comment: You asked this same question earlier and it was closed as a duplicate. You then deleted it and posted this question. Why? What's missing from the duplicate?

Comment: cause the answer of the duplicate question doesn't brings me on